# Images on single product page appears after 2-5seconds

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is website on which I am working - www.inoventary.com

example product page - https://www.inoventary.com/product/new-antigravity-case-iphone/

when we open any product page , images appears after 2-3 seconds and in mobile it takes even more time . All images on example URL are compressed , no render blocking issue , but can't find the problem.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your website is loading tons of resources (javascripts, fonts, dozen of images) at the same time and the images will be displayed on page loading.
I suppose that you are using a plugin that loads photo galleries in that way.

You can try minifing and aggregating resources using a plug-in such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/ in order to optimize page speed.

Comment: I have tried autoptimize already , but not solved . Can you solve if I can give you access to website admin panel?

Comment: No, I won't access to your website: Stackoverflow is not for individual support requests.
But please try these steps, that can you lead to some improvements on page speed side:
Install JetPack and turn on image's lazy loading as described here: https://jetpack.com/support/lazy-images/
or turn on Photon to load images from WP CDN: https://jetpack.com/support/photon/